# Fragments that can be swiped in 4 directions

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-studio-3.0

So basically I want to create an app that when I swipe left it shows a fragment and so as up down and right. Here is the code I have so far

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return ChatFragment.create();
        case 1:
            return EmptyFragment.create();
        case 2:
            return StoryFragment.create();
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

}

I have two more fragments already set up that I want to put on top and below the EmptyFragment. I'm just not sure what code to use or where to put it.